# En codeigniter como puedo saber desde donde se estan enviando los datos?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy editando una pagina en codeingniter pero al parecer tengo 2 archivos que al parecer tienen lo mismo que se llama "Amdmin.php" uno esta alojado en la carpeta de `controllers` y otro en la parte de `views/admin/` y tengo un modelo en `models`

Ahora no se si estructuralmente esto este bien, no tengo experiencia con codeigniter utilizo otro framework pero solo quiero saber 1. si eso esta bien y 2. de donde vienen los datos ya que al hacer

```
<?php var_dump($this->session->userdata()) ?>
```

Solo me trae estos datos

```
array(10) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1565500681) ["user_id"]=> string(3) "798" ["username"]=> string(8) "daniel25" ["first_name"]=> string(13) "DANIEL ARTURO" ["last_name"]=> string(11) "TREJO ROJAS" ["user_level"]=> string(2) "69" ["is_logged_in"]=> bool(true) ["ciudad"]=> NULL ["idSucursal"]=> string(1) "0" ["id_empresa"]=> string(1) "0" }
```

y necesito un dato en especifico que pase desde el modelo o el controlador que en este caso seria

```
idPuesto
```

y esta es la estructura de mi base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---------------code add for login user ------------

```
function login($username, $password) {
    $this->CI->load->model('user');
    $this->CI->load->model('clients_model');

    $result = $this->CI->user->verify_and_get_user($username, $password);

    if ($result['is_true'] == TRUE) {
        foreach ($result['query_result'] as $qr);
            $session_data = array(
                'user_id' => $qr->user_id,
                'username' => $qr->username,
                'first_name' => $qr->first_name,
                'last_name' => $qr->last_name,
                'user_level' => $qr->user_level,
                'is_logged_in' => TRUE,
                'ciudad' => $qr->ciudad,
                'idSucursal' => $qr->idSucursal,
                'id_empresa'=>$qr->id_empresa,
                'idPuesto' => $qr->idPuesto
            );

        $this->CI->session->set_userdata($session_data);

        $data['message'] = $result['message'];
        $data['is_true'] = $result['is_true'];
        $data['is_admin'] = ($qr->user_level == $this->CI->config->item('admin_level') ? TRUE : FALSE);
        $data['is_cliente'] = ($qr->user_level == 2) ? TRUE : FALSE;

        return $data;

    }else{

        $data['message'] = $result['message'];
        $data['is_true'] = $result['is_true'];

        return $data;
    }
}
```

------------verify and get users------------

```
function verify_and_get_user($username, $password) {
    $this->db->select('user_id, username, first_name, last_name, user_level, ciudad, id_empresa, idSucursal');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $this->db->where('status', 'activo');

    $query = $this->db->get('user');

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        //use reference code and dev message for logging/error handling here if needed
        $data['is_true'] = TRUE;
        $data['message'] = $this->config->item('welcome_message');
        $data['query_result'] = $query->result();
        //$data['query_result_array'] = $query->result_array();
        //$data['reference_code'] = '001';
        //$data['dev_message'] = 'User has logged in';
        return $data;
    } elseif ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;
        $data['message'] = 'Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta. Intenta nuevamente.';
        return $data;
    } elseif ($query->num_rows() > 1) {
        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;
        $data['message'] = 'Error al iniciar sesion, por favor contacta al administrador.';
        //$data['reference_code'] = '003';
        //$data['dev_message'] = 'The username and password match more than once in the database.';
        return $data;
    } else {
        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;
        $data['message'] = 'Error inesperado. Intenta nuevamente, si el problema persiste contacta al administrador del sitio.';
        //$data['reference_code'] = '004';
        //$data['dev_message'] = 'Database, script, or site failure.';
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Estructuralmente no hay problema en que se llamen igual, una cosa es una vista y la otra el controlador. 

En cuanto a tu segunda pregunta, ¿tú quieres que el modelo o controlador se encargue de meter ese dato que falta en la sesión para luego poder obtenerlo desde $this->session->userdata()?

Comment: es correcto eso mismo quiero que desde $this->session->userdata() pueda mandar a llamar 'idPuesto'

Comment: Primero deberías averiguar dónde están rellenando esos datos de sesión. Para ello, deberías buscar referencias a $this->session o incluso a $_SESSION.
Cuando lo hagas, por favor, muéstrame el código.

Comment: Encontre uno que segun mi logica es que me esta mandando todos los datos que me esta arrojando con el var_dump te lo adjunto en la pregunta

Comment: Quizás es que no se esté obteniendo de la BDD el dato en cuestión. Esto se debe estar haciendo en el método verify_and_get_user() del modelo User ¿Podrías enseñar la parte de código relevante de este método?

Comment: listo ya lo he agregado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El dato 'idPuesto' no se está pidiendo en la select del modelo y deduzco que por ese motivo no se guarda correctamente en la sesión. Añádelo así a ver qué tal va:

```
function verify_and_get_user($username, $password) {
    $this->db->select('user_id, username, first_name, last_name, user_level, ciudad, id_empresa, idSucursal, idPuesto');
    ...
}
```

Comment: Excelente ya me lo mostro y solo como nota adicional tuve que agregar `'idPuesto'=>$qr->idPuesto,` en el auth.php para que lo enviara bien